# Getting Bootstrap to work in Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass, ruby-on-rails-2

I have worked with Rails 4 earlier and getting bootstrap and sass to work with a Rails 4 application was very easy by doing:

1. Adding gem `'bootstrap-sass'` and gem `'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'` to the `Gemfile` and running `bundle install`
2. Add `//= require bootstrap` line to `application.js`
3. Adding `config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)` line to `application.rb`
4. Adding `@import "bootstrap";` line to the top of the `*.css.scss` file

But the same when done with a Rails 2 application doesnt seem to get the Bootstrap and SCSS to work. Can anybody explain the steps involved in gettin bootstrap and scss to work with a Rails 2 application?

P.S : My application's exact `Rails version is 2.3.18` and am using `Ruby 1.8.7`

Comment: AFAIK rails 2 does not have an asset pipeline, so no asset precompilation. I don't know if sass-rails and bootstrap-sass support rails < 3, but i guess not.

Comment: I got it to work by downloading the bootstrap bundle and putting the corresponding files into the corresponding directory, i.e. js files into public/javascripts, css files into public/stylesheets and images into public/img.